# What is the intended usage of Qt threads in conjunction with dependency injection?

Tags: multithreading, qt, dependency-injection

Let's have a worker thread which is accessed from a wide variety of objects. This worker object has some public slots, so anyone who connects its signals to the worker's slots can use `emit` to trigger the worker thread's useful tasks.

This worker thread needs to be almost global, in the sense that several different classes use it, some of them are deep in the hierarchy (child of a child of a child of the main application).

I guess there are two major ways of doing this:

1. All the methods of the child classes pass their messages upwards the hierarchy via their return values, and let the main (e.g. the GUI) object handle all the emitting.
2. All those classes which require the services of the worker thread have a pointer to the Worker object (which is a member of the main class), and they all `connect()` to it in their constructors. Every such class then does the emitting by itself. Basically, dependency injection.

Option 2. seems much more clean and flexible to me, I'm only worried that it will create a huge number of connections. For example, if I have an array of an object which needs the thread, I will have a separate connection for each element of the array.

Is there an "official" way of doing this, as the creators of Qt intended it?

Comment: If you want to avoid many signal and slot connections, create a new class which emits signals to the worker thread, and pass an instance of that new class to other classes. That way you can use option 2 without a huge number of connections.

Comment: An alternative option is to have the worker class as a singleton, then use [`QMetaObject::invokeMethod`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#invokeMethod) to call its slots, so you need not connect to the instance by every class.

Comment: @thuga : yes, dereferencing and an extra function call should be significantly faster than a signal/slot. I'll do some benchmarks as use a helper class if I don't encounter a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no magic silver bullet for this. You'll need to consider many factors, such as:

- Why do those objects emit the data in the first place? Is it because they need to do something, that is, emission is a “command”? Then maybe they could call some sort of service to do the job without even worrying about whether it's going to happen in another thread or not. Or is it because they inform about an event? In such case they probably should just emit signals but not connect them. Its up to the using code to decide what to do with events.
- How many objects are we talking about? Some performance tests are needed. Maybe it's not even an issue.
- If there is an array of objects, what purpose does it serve? Perhaps instead of using a plain array some sort of “container” class is needed? Then the container could handle the emission and connection and objects could just do something like `container()->handle(data)`. Then you'd only have one connection per container.

Comment: This is not very different from my original line of thought, the main reason I asked this question was the off chance that Qt might offer something special which I might have overlooked (As I rarely needed to use Qt threads before, besides one-shot number-crunching scenarios, where subclassing `QThread` was the simplest way to go)